# Buy 3 get 2 free not working

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to apply cart price for one item, buy 3 get 2 free.
I set discount amount = 2 & buy x = 3.. after that I set a rule only for SKU of that item.
But it's not working !
When I put 4 qty in the cart I get only 1 free !

Could you please advise.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Cart Price Rules - Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y) works as follows :
[image]

Now please add to cart product with qty 2 and apply this coupon code now you will get one product price as a discount.

Actually there is no any facility that magento give buy 1 get 1 free automatic so we have to add product with qty 2 and apply rule then we get the discount.

Answer (score 0):

It's Buy X meaning you have to Pay for X.

Now, let's take X = 2, Y = 1, price = $5. Buy 2 get 1 free.

Meaning, you have to Spend money or pay for 2 = 10$, now you are having 2 product in hand and store will give you 1 free => You are having 3 products in total.

So in this case, we have to put 3 in cart (3 = X + Y) to get Y free.

Another example: Buy 6 get 3 => you have to put 9 products in cart.

Answer (score 0):

There are few different reasons for that please check below some points.

1. The promotion is not enabled: Make sure that the promotion is
   enabled in the Magento 2 admin panel under **"Marketing" ->
   "Promotions" -> "Shopping Cart Price Rules"**.
2. The promotion is not applied to the correct products: Make sure that
   the products included in the promotion are specified correctly in
   the "Actions" section of the promotion. You should also check that
   the products are in the correct categories and that the promotion is
   not conflicting with other promotions.
3. The promotion is not applied to the correct customer groups: Make
   sure that the promotion is applied to the correct customer groups in
   the "Conditions" section of the promotion.
4. The promotion is not applied correctly in the cart: Make sure that
   the promotion is applied correctly in the cart by checking the
   totals and discounts.
5. The promotion is not applied correctly in the order: Make sure that
   the promotion is applied correctly in the order by checking the
   order totals and discounts in the **"Sales" -> "Orders" section of the
   Magento 2 admin panel**.

Here is an example of how you can create a "buy 3 get 2 free" promotion in Magento 2:

1. Go to the Magento 2 admin panel and navigate to **"Marketing" ->
   "Promotions" -> "Shopping Cart Price Rules"**.
2. Click on the "Add New Rule" button.
3. Fill in the rule information like **"Rule Name", "Description",
   "Status", "Website", "Customer Groups" and "From-To dates"**
4. In the **"Conditions"** section, select **"If an item is found"** and then
   choose the **"SKU"** and set the **"Quantity"** to 3.
5. In the **"Actions"** section, select **"Buy X get Y free (discount amount
   is Y)"** and then set the **"Discount Amount"** to 2 and the **"Maximum Qty
   Discount is Applied to"** to 2.
6. Save the rule

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**